# How do I add the values in a list together? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm currently learning Python and for my task it says to add the values of an array together. I tried:

```
no = ['1','2','3']
sum(no)
```

but had no luck in figuring out any way to find an answer. I'm also not supposed to use the `sum` function.

Here's an example of the question if you need more info:

> Define a function `sumStudentNo()` that will add the individual digits
>   of your student number (excluding any letters) using an array and
>   display the answer. E.g. If your student number is `'s3456789'`, your
>   program should display `42` (ignore the `'s'`).
>
> Note you must NOT use the
>   `sum` function.

Please help me.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried already.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not allowed to use `sum` (as in `sum(int(n) for n in no)`), then you have to 1) convert every list element using `int` and 2) sum them up.

```
s = 0
for n in no:
    try:
        s += int(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: What happens when this hits a letter?

Comment: @Keith That's not what is asked in the question. Feel free to answer with a more robust solution.

Comment: @Tichodrama The actual task states "...(excluding any letters) "

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 0
no = "12p3s"
for i in no:
    if i.isdigit():
        s = s + int(i)
print s
```